# Java generics inheritance & Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have a 4 classes: A extends B, C extends D. And the following code:

```
class B
{ 
    Set<D> mySet;

    public Set<D> getMySet()
    {....}

    public void setMySet(Set<D> setset)
    {....}
}

class A extends B
{
    Set<C> mySet;

    public Set<C> getMySet()
    {....}

    public void setMySet(Set<C> setset)
    {....}
}
```

class A doesn't compile because get/set have same erasure with parent class. If I remove types of set in A it compiles well but then I have hibernate error because the class is mapped. Mapping for A is simple without info about inheritance. Can I somehow dont change mapping hbm.xml and make things work without changing class B(I cant because it's lib provided)? What is best solution in this case without changing B class?

Comment: Does B support generics? Like Class B<D>?

Comment: Also do you have C extends D?

Comment: This design is really suspect - for one your overrides aren't correct from a type safety perspective. How is calling (`((B) new A()).setMySet(new Set<D>())` supposed to work? This would call the `setMySet(Set<C>)` override and you clearly can't pass a `Set<D>` to a `Set<C>` parameter. Are you sure inheritance is the way to go here? Within the framework of Java's type system it would be better to just make a new property or make `A` wrap a `B` instead of inheriting from it.

Comment: @zenbeni Does B support generics? Like Class B<D>? No Also do you have C extends D? yes

Comment: @millimoose I extend B because I want to use my realization in code that uses B, that code is also unchangeable and uses generics with<B> type parameters

Comment: @Martin But your implementation attempts to make incompatible changes to `B`'s interface. And is likely an abuse of inheritance. And I have no idea how an ORM would actually persist this - inheritance mapping usually only deals with new properties being added, not with one actually changing type.